# Add a foreign key column to Identity database using code first in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I would like to extend my AspNetUsers table with a foreign key attribute, CustomerID.

I managed to migrate the ASP.NET Identity Database with our own created database. So the Identity tables and the tables in our own created database, now share the exact same database.

However, I would like to map a relation between AspNetUsers and Customer using code first. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Override this in your db context and do something similar but with your Customer:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
```